# port not listening for apns daemon using twisted on windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, twisted

I'm trying to get the apns daemon at http://code.google.com/p/apnsd/ working, and am having problems with networking. I've configured the daemon to listen on port 1055 (but I've also tried other ports). I can start the daemon and it seems to work ok (including connecting to the apple servers), but I can't see the network port being open and listening when I type netstat -a. I am running on Windows 7, and have turned off Windows firewall (so I don't think it's a firewall problem).

I've successfully run the twisted demo server and client at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/index.html (simpleclient.py & simpleserv.py) on a variety of ports, and can also confirm that the ports appear in netstat -a, so I don't think that the problem is in installation/configuration of OS/python/twisted/other required modules.

I believe the relevant code (print statements added by myself) in the dameon is:

```
print "LISTENING TCP SERVER"
print "PORT", listener_data["port"], listener_data["port"].__repr__
server = internet.TCPServer(listener_data["port"], listener)
print server
```

I would have thought that after executing this line the port will appear is open in netstat -a. Can anyone suggest what the problem is, or provide suggestions as to how to diagnose further?

I don't think it's relevant, but my apns daemon configuration is:

```
{
    'listeners': {
        'line': {
            'class': 'apnsd.listeners.line.LineProtocolFactory',
            # 'interface': "192.168.1.3",  #default: all interface
            'port':1055,
        },
    },

    'apps': {
        'gp': {
            'apns_dev': {
                'app_id':           "xxx",
                'app_class':        "xxx",
                'certificate_file': "F:/cert_file.pem",
                'privatekey_file':  "F:/pk_unencrypted.pem",
            },
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting the daemon using twistd instead of with main.py.

The twistd script is Twisted's utility to turn a twisted app into a service.  The usage is:

```
$PYTHON_ROOT/bin/twistd apnsd -c $APNSD_CONFIG
```

This would start apnsd as a daemon.  To not daemonize it, simply pass in the -n parameter:

```
$PYTHON_ROOT/bin/twistd -n apnsd -c $APNSD_CONFIG
```